# Word for part of speech before the main speech

Tags: single-word-requests

**I am not trying to troll anybody, although it might seem like it. Also, this is not intended to be funny or anything.** The question I wanted to ask is what do you call the part of a narration/talk/speech/short-paragraph such as this, that is dedicated as sort of disclaimer, preface or something secondary to the main topic. For example, the bolded part of this paragraph.

Example: Your #the-word-i-am-looking-for#* is unnecessary; I wouldn't have taken it as a troll.

**Sorry for repeating myself**, but this is another example.

Comment: Maybe a *disclaimer*?

Comment: Thanks Dan. I think disclaimer might work for the first paragraph, but will it also work for the second example I added? There there a more generic word?

Comment: Those both look like apologies to me. Or *apologia* if you want a fancy term with a more precise definition matching your use. Either way, *apologia* need not be prefatory, so 'prefatory apologia' might be best.

Answer (score 3):

**Preamble**, defined by [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/preamble) as "a preliminary or preparatory statement; an introduction."

Comment: you should add your source and a link to the source.

Comment: I added a citation for and a link to the source of the quoted language. As ab2 notes, you should perform this task yourself when quoting other people's language.

Comment: Thank you. I am new here and surely have a lot to learn!